# How to get input alt-title when insert image on CKEditor 5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

I am trying to get the alt text when inserting images in ckeditor 5, however I don't know how.

My code snippet

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev) {
var dialogName = ev.data.name;
var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
var dialog = dialogDefinition.dialog;
var editor = ev.editor;

if (dialogName == 'image') {
    dialogDefinition.onOk = function (e) {
        var imageSrcUrl = e.sender.originalElement.$.src;
        console.log(e.sender);
        var length = imageSrcUrl.length;
        var pos = imageSrcUrl.indexOf('source') + 6;
        var res = imageSrcUrl.substring(pos, length);
        imageSrcUrl = res.replace(/^.*\/\/[^\/]+/, '');
        var width = e.sender.originalElement.$.width;
        var height = e.sender.originalElement.$.height;
        var imgHtml = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml('<div>[img src="'+ imageSrcUrl +'" alt=""]<img class="lazyload" src="' + imageSrcUrl +  '" />[/img]</div>');
        editor.insertElement(imgHtml);
    };
}
```

});

I tried

```
console.log(e.sender)
```

But i don't khown where parameter stored this.

Comment: you can use `alt` inside your `<img>` tag like `<img alt="something>`

Comment: This alt text, users enter through "insert image dialog", not default text.